# Mount windows server 2012 DVD on centos 7

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, centos7

I'm trying to install windows server 2012 R2 on a VM using virt-manager on centos 7. During the install it will not allow me to select the DVD drive (greyed out).

I tried the following command:

mount -r -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /mnt/DVD/

The DVD mounted without error but there is only one file:

readme.txt

This disc contains a "UDF" file system and requires an operating system
that supports the ISO-13346 "UDF" file system specification.

So I tried the following command:
mount -r -t iso13346 /dev/sr0 /mnt/DVD/

got this error:
mount: unknown filesystem type 'iso13346'

Could it be that the DVD drive I'm using is too old? It was manufactured in 2003...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't specify a filesystem type; mount will figure it out (correctly).

And if you're trying to install Windows in a virtual machine, you do not need to (and should not) mount the image at all. Simply provide the path to the ISO when setting up the VM in virt-manager.

[image: Virt-manager install media selection page]

Comment: That worked, however if I only have the DVD and no .iso do I have to make an iso file from the DVD?

Comment: No, you just point virt-manager at the DVD drive.

Comment: DVD option is still greyed out says "Media Unknown (dev/sr0)"

Comment: You have to actually click the radio button!

Comment: It will not allow me to. it's "greyed out"... not click-able....

Comment: "Use CDROM or DVD" is grayed out? Maybe you should ask a new question.